# Can't run Bundle install in Cygwin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drupal-7, cygwin, drush

I'm kind of new to omega 4 and i'm working on windows 8 and Cygwin .
when i go to my sub-theme with drush or cygwin and run `bundle install` i get error like this :

```
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

and version of ruby is : `ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [i386-cygwin]`
any idea ? THx

Comment: what says: `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` ?

Comment: atfer runnig bundle install in cgywin the error said Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'`

Comment: I understood, but what says pure call to: `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'`?

Comment: what? just execute `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` instead of `bundle install` in cygwin's cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see more detail of the `gem install` process (including compile output) run the command directly with verbose `-V`

```
gem install eventmachine -V -v '1.0.3'
```

You will need the `c++` build tools and a [couple of other packages](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/Building-EventMachine) installed in Cygwin to build the eventmachine native extension

Add these packages to cygwin via [setup](https://www.cygwin.com/install.html) or [`apt-cyg`](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg)

```
gcc-core gcc-g++ make binutils w32api openssl openssl-devel zlib zlib-devel
```

Then try the gem install again, with `-V` if you still have failures.

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'
```

Comment: one more question : after run bundle install i get this one : gem install ffi -v '1.9.3'

Comment: Ask another question with the `gem install ffi -V -v '1.9.3'` output attached.

Comment: Thx a lot and this page helped me alot
https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/284#issuecomment-33752957

Comment: More packages! No worries.

Comment: Finally, someone knows what their doing!